# Should I add my upcoming job as my current position?

Tags: linkedin

So I'm starting at a new job in a few weeks. I've quit my previous jobs some time ago so my 'current position' on LinkedIn has been empty for a quite a while, even though I've already settled on a new position.

This has the uneasy result that recruiters think I'm unemployed and are flocking on me like crazy. This makes me want to update my 'current position' with my upcoming job.

My question: what are potential considerations in doing this? Will it come across weird to my new employer? Will it seem unprofessional? Could I seem somehow less employable for having no job for such an amount of time?

Should I feel comfortable doing this?

Comment: I added my current job on linkedin before I started here. It was only a couple weeks and you can't set the start date to a future date so I went in and changed it after I actually started but I don't think it is that big a deal.

Comment: @EvanSteinbrenner is right, it is not _technically_ possible to add a job with Start Date in the future. LinkedIn will say: __Start date can’t be past today’s date.__ Here is a related link: [2014 April 17, Lavie Margolin: Found a job? Don't update your LinkedIn profile yet!!](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140417163736-10326243-found-a-job-don-t-update-your-linkedin-profile-yet/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never ever add a position to my resume at least until my first day on the job. Until you have actually started, it's never a sure thing (even after you start it's not necessarily a sure thing. One startup I worked at went through 3 CTOs in a month - getting rid of each one a week after they started.) A few weeks shouldn't make a difference in your employability, however if you have a linkedin pro subscription or are marked as actively seeking employment you may want to cancel it so that you aren't coming up at the top of recruiters search results.

Answer (score 6):

Recruiters are gonna do what they do. It won't probably change if you're employed and have hot skills that will make them a buck.  If they don't bug you, they get nothing.

No need to react, or do anything.  They'll go away.